# Sort, by the difference of two numbers

Tags: r

I want to sort an array in increasing way, by the difference of the biggest and smallest number.
Without loops.

I think I need a sort that I can give a condition but i can't find how.

Something like this:

```
sort(arr, decreasing = FALSE, by = max(a) - min(a))
sort(arr, decreasing = FALSE, condition = max(a) - min(a))
```

The sorted array have to look like this. The difference from the first and second number is the smallest for all numbers int the array, the difference from the second and the third is the second smallest ......

Example: // I thing is like this

array(22, 2, 32, 3, 6, 9, 7, 23, 11, 13)

sorted_array(9, 11, 7, 13, 6, 22, 3, 23, 2, 32)

I thing another way is to construct the sorted array be putting on the last position the biggest number after that the smallest, the second biggest, the second smallest, ...

Sorry for the bad explanation.

Comment: It isn't completely clear what you are trying to do. The description of the intended sort seems to underspecify it.

Comment: I am sorry but my english isn't soo good and i can't find a better way to explain it.

Comment: Jep, i also don't understand what your looking for. You mentioned that you don't want that a loop solve your question, but maybe you can provide a loop to understand what you want.

Comment: pretty much i have to find the biggest difference that is from the biggest and smallest number and sort the array from the smallest difference to the biggest difference

Comment: The problem is that you have `n(n-1)/2` distinct pairs of numbers, which you want to sort -- by sorting the `n` numbers themselves. In effect, you are trying to do something like a nearest-neighbor path through a weighted graph, but such paths are not unique, hence my comment.

Comment: An example of how you sort is underspecified -- why should your example begin 9, 11 rather than any of 2, 3 or 3, 2, or 6, 7, or 7, 6, or 22, 23, or 23, 22? Those ordered pairs all have distance 1, hence would seem to satisfy that "the difference from the first and second number is the smallest for all numbers in the array" rather than the 9, 11 that you give. There are 6 ordered pairs of numbers that satisfy that condition you gave for the first two numbers. You give no criterion to decide among those 6, but instead pick another pair, with no reason given.

Comment: @JohnColeman: I think he like to start in the end, with 32 and 2, the consequence is with this method  9 and 11 are just remaining in the end.

Comment: @and seems like a reasonable guess of OP's intention, which would make their description of it simply wrong. On the other hand, the example might just illustrate the heuristic that they are using, with the example showing a failure of the heuristic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a idea how it could work, but only for arrays where the length is even. If you want to use this solution and you have uneven arrays, you can work with `if`. I need to admit that it have to be urgent, that I would like to use a construction like this instead of a loop.

```
x <- c(22, 2, 32, 3, 6, 9, 7, 23, 11, 13)
n <- length(x)
m <- floor(n/2)

rev(
 as.numeric(
  rbind(
   sort(x)[n-c(0:(m-1))],
   sort(x)[1:m]
  )
 )
)
```

Comment: Thank you, I think that may work for me. And Yes The length is even I forgot to mention it.

Answer (score 0):

I attempted to come up with a non-for-loop construction. So I first sorted the sequence and then split it in two halves by naming the first half "a_N" and second half "b_N", then "folded it " into a two column matrix with the first half reversed, and finally read it out by unfolding with `c`:

```
my_arr <- c(22, 2, 32, 3, 6, 9, 7, 23, 11, 13)
names(my_arr) <- paste0( rep( c("a","b"), each=length(my_arr)/2), order(my_arr) )
c( rbind( sort( my_arr[grep("a", names(my_arr))], decreasing=TRUE), #first half
           my_arr[grep("b", names(my_arr))]) )  # second half
 #[1]  9 11  7 13  6 22  3 23  2 32
```

You can see the intermediate value of the matrix:

```
rbind( sort( my_arr[grep("a", names(my_arr))], decreasing=TRUE), my_arr[grep("b", names(my_arr))])
     a5 a4 a3 a2 a1
[1,]  9  7  6  3  2
[2,] 11 13 22 23 32
```

And since R matrices are read out in column order you get the desired interleaving with `c()` which also removes the names.